# How to query an external data source at send time

Tags: marketing-cloud

Many of our current campaigns use ampscript to pull in content dynamically at send time. The ampscript looks up into data extensions that have been populated prior to the send (i.e. we run a query on an external database and then import the results of the query into a data extension).

Is there a way to perform a lookup into the external database at send time so that we are getting the most up-to-date information instead of using potentially outdated information in the data extension? If this functionality exists, is it flexible enough to leverage elastic search instead of the typical relational database query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You should create REST route on the external system to get the data.  Then, use the AMPscript HTTPGet functionality at send time to get the latest and greatest info to populate the email.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm

Comment: can you clarify how to create a REST route, I would like to use this functionality to retrieve Images URL from our DAM Bynder